# Creating a WPA2 Enterprise Connection On Ubuntu Touch

Tags: networking, wireless, ubuntu-touch, wpa2

I've recently flashed ubuntu touch onto a nexus 7. Its great, but i can't get it to connect to the WPA2 Enterprise network that is the main source of internet in my university (specifically eduroam). I have tried using the official eduroam bash script as well as creating a custom network manager configuration and an attempt at using wpa_supplicant. Im out of ideas and seemingly so is google. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that NetworkManager needs the entries to be properly formatted and needs the cert to work with enterprise connections. For those of you stumped, eduroam offers a script on their website that will generate the correct connection file for you and install the cert, but you need to have python installed, and to my knowledge the devel channel does not come with python prinstalled. Here is a sample config file for eduroam.

```
[connection]
id=eduroam
uuid=89feacc0-bf73-48b1-92bf-3fb57b735c89
type=802-11-wireless`

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=eduroam
security=802-11-wireless-security

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
method=auto

[802-1x]
eap=ttls;
identity=<$YOURIDENTITY>
anonymous-identity=<$ANONYMOUSIDENTITY>
ca-cert=~/.eduroam/ca.pem  #Replace the tilde with the absolute path
phase2-auth=mschapv2
password=<$YOURPASSWORD>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the mentioned script please? I can't seem to find it anywhere on the official site... Thanks.

Comment: Here it is! The have them preconfigured for your institution. https://cat.eduroam.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have done it for my BQ Aquaris E4.5 using the followign template:

https://github.com/AKSW/dssnp/blob/master/network-conf/NetworkManager/system-connections/eduroam

I downloaded the file on my PC, modified it to my credentials, and uploaded it to the phone via bluetooth.

I then used the terminal to place the file in `/etc/NetwrokManager/system-connections/eduroam`

As soon as I turned WiFi on on the phone I got the connection.

Yes, it is a hack, but it works very well until the GUI supports the option.

If you use eduroam in your computer, you can get more information in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. You might find information regarding certificates there.

Comment: I had no luck with your link @Stunts neither with [this one](http://www.danbishop.org/2015/02/21/add-eduroam-or-any-other-802-1x-wireless-network-to-ubuntu-phone/). Did you use and, if so, where did you put the cert file? How did you generate it?

Comment: Good point. My university does not use certificates, and therefore there was no need to worry about it. I have edited the answer for an alternative way to generate a template.