# Cannot Connect to WPA2 Enterprise on Ubuntu Phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, network-manager

I wrote a NetworkManager config file by myself and I also tried [the one](https://github.com/AKSW/dssnp/blob/master/network-conf/NetworkManager/system-connections/eduroam)  mentioned by Stunts in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586300/creating-a-wpa2-enterprise-connection-on-ubuntu-touch). I put each of them into

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

but nothing happens. I reenabled WiFi, rebooted the device, etc., but it doesn't help. Running

```
nmcli con list
```

does not include any of the WPA Enterprise connections. I tried to run something like

```
nmcli con reload
```

as mentioned [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/SystemSettings), but, obviously, this is not working for NM version 0.9.8.8, but only for >= 0.9.10.0. I only get the result

```
Error: 'con' command 'reload' is not valid.
```

I'm running a BQ Aquaris E4.5.